# How to change the logoURL dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am creating a Gmail Add-ons.
(Sample is working)

I would like to dynamically change logoUrl, but that way does not seem to be defined.
(ex. Change to a specific logo when receiving a specific e-mail address. etc)

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible.

Think about it from a user's perspective. One day the logo in the sidebar changes and he/she will be wondering what happened.